# Finding a pattern or formula to convert Sketch shape path points(json format) to svg path

Tags: json, svg, discrete-mathematics, sketchapp, sketch-3

I am trying to find a pattern to convert Sketch shape points(json format) to svg path, as we know sketch files are just zip files, unzipping you will get json files. 
here are sample json codes

```
{
    "_class": "triangle",
    "do_objectID": "BE50CDBE-491C-4402-98EA-71E9C7B9F61B",
    "booleanOperation": -1,
    "frame": {
        "_class": "rect",
        "do_objectID": "0B39EF6D-9AD4-409B-85FA-D09B2B8A0692",
        "constrainProportions": false,
        "height": 56.86153846153846,
        "width": 66,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
    },
    "isFixedToViewport": false,
    "isFlippedHorizontal": false,
    "isFlippedVertical": false,
    "isLocked": false,
    "isVisible": true,
    "layerListExpandedType": 1,
    "name": "Triangle",
    "nameIsFixed": false,
    "resizingConstraint": 63,
    "resizingType": 0,
    "rotation": 0,
    "shouldBreakMaskChain": false,
    "userInfo": {
        "com.animaapp.stc-sketch-plugin": {
            "kModelPropertiesKey": {}
        }
    },
    "clippingMaskMode": 0,
    "hasClippingMask": false,
    "edited": false,
    "isClosed": true,
    "pointRadiusBehaviour": 1,
    "points": [
        {
            "_class": "curvePoint",
            "cornerRadius": 0,
            "curveFrom": "{0.49999999999999944, 0}",
            "curveMode": 1,
            "curveTo": "{0.49999999999999944, 0}",
            "hasCurveFrom": false,
            "hasCurveTo": false,
            "point": "{0.49999999999999944, 0}"
        },
        {
            "_class": "curvePoint",
            "cornerRadius": 0,
            "curveFrom": "{0.99999999999999889, 1}",
            "curveMode": 1,
            "curveTo": "{0.99999999999999889, 1}",
            "hasCurveFrom": false,
            "hasCurveTo": false,
            "point": "{0.99999999999999889, 1}"
        },
        {
            "_class": "curvePoint",
            "cornerRadius": 0,
            "curveFrom": "{0, 1}",
            "curveMode": 1,
            "curveTo": "{0, 1}",
            "hasCurveFrom": false,
            "hasCurveTo": false,
            "point": "{0, 1}"
        }
    ],
    "isEquilateral": false
}
```

this gives a Triangle with its svg path code

```
<polygon id="Triangle" points="33 0 66 56.8615385 0 56.8615385"></polygon>
```

for my understanding `getting 33(x value)` is done as follows, since above frame origin is at `0,0 (frame->x, frame->y)` i thought to get its actual position is to take `frame->width`(since width corresponds to x axis) which is `66 times first x point in points, which is 0.49999999999999944`, resulting to (`32.99999999 approx 33`), and `first y point` taking `frame->height(56.86153846153846 times the first y point in points which is 0)` resulting to the first point be `33 0`

second point the same, to get x is taking `frame->width(66)` times `second x point in points which is 0.99999999` resulting to `66`, same with its `corresponding y (56.86153846153846 times 1) which is 56.86153846153846`, resulting to second point be `66 56.86153846153846` goes the same to third point..

**Starts confusing if frame->x and frame->y has numbers greater than 0**

consider this..

```
{
    "_class": "triangle",
    "do_objectID": "BB3FB5DE-F0A8-4AAD-8009-14F908023F19",
    "booleanOperation": -1,
    "frame": {
        "_class": "rect",
        "do_objectID": "316A9A7C-D0BF-4D71-BC65-1A0301846F20",
        "constrainProportions": true,
        "height": 32.49230769230769,
        "width": 37.56923076923076,
        "x": 14.21538461538461,
        "y": 22.33846153846153
    },
    "isFixedToViewport": false,
    "isFlippedHorizontal": false,
    "isFlippedVertical": false,
    "isLocked": false,
    "isVisible": true,
    "layerListExpandedType": 1,
    "name": "Triangle",
    "nameIsFixed": false,
    "resizingConstraint": 63,
    "resizingType": 0,
    "rotation": -180,
    "shouldBreakMaskChain": false,
    "userInfo": {
        "com.animaapp.stc-sketch-plugin": {
            "kModelPropertiesKey": {
                "constraints": {
                    "scaleFactor": 1,
                    "model_version": 0.1,
                    "aspectRatio": {
                        "multiplier": 37.56923,
                        "enabled": 1,
                        "model_version": 0.1,
                        "modelID": "constraint_dd3b6146-988c-411d-94e1-cb5ec2a60bc8",
                        "model_class": "ADModelConstraint",
                        "constant": 32.49231
                    },
                    "modelID": "viewConstraints_7f13ceae-6706-4965-b3af-3cde627fd97c",
                    "model_class": "ADModelViewConstraints",
                    "automatic": 1
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "clippingMaskMode": 0,
    "hasClippingMask": false,
    "edited": false,
    "isClosed": true,
    "pointRadiusBehaviour": 1,
    "points": [
        {
            "_class": "curvePoint",
            "cornerRadius": 0,
            "curveFrom": "{0.4999999999999995, 0}",
            "curveMode": 1,
            "curveTo": "{0.4999999999999995, 0}",
            "hasCurveFrom": false,
            "hasCurveTo": false,
            "point": "{0.4999999999999995, 0}"
        },
        {
            "_class": "curvePoint",
            "cornerRadius": 0,
            "curveFrom": "{0.999999999999999, 1.0000000000000009}",
            "curveMode": 1,
            "curveTo": "{0.999999999999999, 1.0000000000000009}",
            "hasCurveFrom": false,
            "hasCurveTo": false,
            "point": "{0.999999999999999, 1.0000000000000009}"
        },
        {
            "_class": "curvePoint",
            "cornerRadius": 0,
            "curveFrom": "{0, 1.0000000000000009}",
            "curveMode": 1,
            "curveTo": "{0, 1.0000000000000009}",
            "hasCurveFrom": false,
            "hasCurveTo": false,
            "point": "{0, 1.0000000000000009}"
        }
    ],
    "isEquilateral": false
}
```

its corresponding svg path is

```
<polygon id="Triangle" transform="translate(33.000000, 38.584615) rotate(180.000000) translate(-33.000000, -38.584615) " points="33 22.3384615 51.7846154 54.8307692 14.2153846 54.8307692"></polygon>
```

Now if i do my math as above, i don't get `points="33 22.3384615 51.7846154 54.8307692 14.2153846 54.8307692"` as above svg code shows. This is only for triangle, if is a custom shape path like facebook icon, it confuses alot!. Sample sketch logo,

[image: Sketch Facebook Icon]

its corresponding Sketch json code is as follows.

```
{
    "_class": "group",
    "do_objectID": "4AA67C64-14B8-433F-8569-9BF7BAEC2914",
    "booleanOperation": -1,
    "frame": {
        "_class": "rect",
        "do_objectID": "1FB80667-369B-4F79-9D8E-76ABD9065B12",
        "constrainProportions": true,
        "height": 50,
        "width": 50,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
    },
    "isFixedToViewport": false,
    "isFlippedHorizontal": false,
    "isFlippedVertical": false,
    "isLocked": false,
    "isVisible": true,
    "layerListExpandedType": 0,
    "name": "Facebook",
    "nameIsFixed": true,
    "resizingConstraint": 63,
    "resizingType": 0,
    "rotation": 0,
    "shouldBreakMaskChain": false,
    "userInfo": {
        "com.animaapp.stc-sketch-plugin": {
            "kModelPropertiesKey": {
                "constraints": {
                    "scaleFactor": 1,
                    "model_version": 0.1,
                    "aspectRatio": {
                        "constant": 50,
                        "enabled": 1,
                        "multiplier": 50,
                        "modelID": "constraint_c03c7307-1fe6-4ded-9d49-e35c2e25c117",
                        "model_class": "ADModelConstraint",
                        "model_version": 0.1
                    },
                    "modelID": "viewConstraints_b34c9514-3166-464d-a3dd-f968c4f6144b",
                    "model_class": "ADModelViewConstraints",
                    "automatic": 1
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "clippingMaskMode": 0,
    "hasClippingMask": false,
    "hasClickThrough": false,
    "layers": [
        {
            "_class": "oval",
            "do_objectID": "DA55B46C-1069-46DC-AAD6-78DCC03F4B3C",
            "booleanOperation": -1,
            "frame": {
                "_class": "rect",
                "do_objectID": "58627B0B-C1B7-4C33-BF5C-2B0F6F0DBC8E",
                "constrainProportions": true,
                "height": 50,
                "width": 50,
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0
            },
            "isFixedToViewport": false,
            "isFlippedHorizontal": false,
            "isFlippedVertical": false,
            "isLocked": false,
            "isVisible": true,
            "layerListExpandedType": 0,
            "name": "Oval",
            "nameIsFixed": false,
            "resizingConstraint": 63,
            "resizingType": 0,
            "rotation": 0,
            "shouldBreakMaskChain": false,
            "userInfo": {
                "com.animaapp.stc-sketch-plugin": {
                    "kModelPropertiesKey": {
                        "constraints": {
                            "scaleFactor": 1,
                            "model_version": 0.1,
                            "aspectRatio": {
                                "constant": 32,
                                "enabled": 1,
                                "multiplier": 32,
                                "modelID": "constraint_5868769e-cc0b-4eec-a4af-d965ce1b6520",
                                "model_class": "ADModelConstraint",
                                "model_version": 0.1
                            },
                            "modelID": "viewConstraints_9d4aa04f-2445-427e-9182-b1ce723cefd2",
                            "model_class": "ADModelViewConstraints",
                            "automatic": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "clippingMaskMode": 0,
            "hasClippingMask": false,
            "edited": false,
            "isClosed": true,
            "pointRadiusBehaviour": 1,
            "points": [
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{0.77614237490000004, 1}",
                    "curveMode": 2,
                    "curveTo": "{0.22385762510000001, 1}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": true,
                    "hasCurveTo": true,
                    "point": "{0.5, 1}"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{1, 0.22385762510000001}",
                    "curveMode": 2,
                    "curveTo": "{1, 0.77614237490000004}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": true,
                    "hasCurveTo": true,
                    "point": "{1, 0.5}"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{0.22385762510000001, 0}",
                    "curveMode": 2,
                    "curveTo": "{0.77614237490000004, 0}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": true,
                    "hasCurveTo": true,
                    "point": "{0.5, 0}"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{0, 0.77614237490000004}",
                    "curveMode": 2,
                    "curveTo": "{0, 0.22385762510000001}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": true,
                    "hasCurveTo": true,
                    "point": "{0, 0.5}"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_class": "shapePath",
            "do_objectID": "C96926E4-56B4-4816-A68B-22789ACF9811",
            "booleanOperation": -1,
            "frame": {
                "_class": "rect",
                "do_objectID": "33C190C2-C868-48CC-B5A5-E033A65A5DC5",
                "constrainProportions": false,
                "height": 30,
                "width": 14,
                "x": 17,
                "y": 10
            },
            "isFixedToViewport": false,
            "isFlippedHorizontal": false,
            "isFlippedVertical": false,
            "isLocked": false,
            "isVisible": true,
            "layerListExpandedType": 1,
            "name": "facebook [#176]",
            "nameIsFixed": false,
            "resizingConstraint": 63,
            "resizingType": 0,
            "rotation": 0,
            "shouldBreakMaskChain": false,
            "userInfo": {
                "com.animaapp.stc-sketch-plugin": {
                    "kModelPropertiesKey": {}
                }
            },
            "clippingMaskMode": 0,
            "hasClippingMask": false,
            "edited": true,
            "isClosed": true,
            "pointRadiusBehaviour": 0,
            "points": [
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{0.68212824010914053, 1}",
                    "curveMode": 1,
                    "curveTo": "{0.68212824010914053, 1}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": false,
                    "hasCurveTo": false,
                    "point": "{0.68212824010914053, 1}"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{0.68212824010914053, 0.55000000000000004}",
                    "curveMode": 1,
                    "curveTo": "{0.68212824010914053, 0.55000000000000004}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": false,
                    "hasCurveTo": false,
                    "point": "{0.68212824010914053, 0.55000000000000004}"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{0.95536932371857075, 0.55000000000000004}",
                    "curveMode": 1,
                    "curveTo": "{0.95536932371857075, 0.55000000000000004}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": false,
                    "hasCurveTo": false,
                    "point": "{0.95536932371857075, 0.55000000000000004}"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{1, 0.34999999999999998}",
                    "curveMode": 1,
                    "curveTo": "{1, 0.34999999999999998}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": false,
                    "hasCurveTo": false,
                    "point": "{1, 0.34999999999999998}"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{0.68212824010914053, 0.34999999999999998}",
                    "curveMode": 1,
                    "curveTo": "{0.68212824010914053, 0.34999999999999998}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": false,
                    "hasCurveTo": false,
                    "point": "{0.68212824010914053, 0.34999999999999998}"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{0.68212824010914053, 0.20109999999999956}",
                    "curveMode": 4,
                    "curveTo": "{0.68212824010914053, 0.2525999999999996}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": true,
                    "hasCurveTo": false,
                    "point": "{0.68212824010914053, 0.2525999999999996}"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{0.82868836484116337, 0.14999999999999999}",
                    "curveMode": 4,
                    "curveTo": "{0.68475930617813163, 0.14999999999999999}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": false,
                    "hasCurveTo": true,
                    "point": "{0.82868836484116337, 0.14999999999999999}"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{0.97446891444162931, 0.14999999999999999}",
                    "curveMode": 1,
                    "curveTo": "{0.97446891444162931, 0.14999999999999999}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": false,
                    "hasCurveTo": false,
                    "point": "{0.97446891444162931, 0.14999999999999999}"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{0.97446891444162931, 0.0048499999999989992}",
                    "curveMode": 4,
                    "curveTo": "{0.97446891444162931, 0.0069999999999993175}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": true,
                    "hasCurveTo": false,
                    "point": "{0.97446891444162931, 0.0069999999999993175}"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{0.45800038978756463, 0}",
                    "curveMode": 3,
                    "curveTo": "{0.84924965893587745, 0}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": true,
                    "hasCurveTo": true,
                    "point": "{0.72256870005847007, 0}"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{0.29234067433248878, 0.23499999999999943}",
                    "curveMode": 4,
                    "curveTo": "{0.29234067433248878, 0.082849999999999119}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": false,
                    "hasCurveTo": true,
                    "point": "{0.29234067433248878, 0.23499999999999943}"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{0.29234067433248878, 0.34999999999999998}",
                    "curveMode": 1,
                    "curveTo": "{0.29234067433248878, 0.34999999999999998}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": false,
                    "hasCurveTo": false,
                    "point": "{0.29234067433248878, 0.34999999999999998}"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{0, 0.34999999999999998}",
                    "curveMode": 1,
                    "curveTo": "{0, 0.34999999999999998}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": false,
                    "hasCurveTo": false,
                    "point": "{0, 0.34999999999999998}"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{0, 0.55000000000000004}",
                    "curveMode": 1,
                    "curveTo": "{0, 0.55000000000000004}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": false,
                    "hasCurveTo": false,
                    "point": "{0, 0.55000000000000004}"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{0.29234067433248878, 0.55000000000000004}",
                    "curveMode": 1,
                    "curveTo": "{0.29234067433248878, 0.55000000000000004}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": false,
                    "hasCurveTo": false,
                    "point": "{0.29234067433248878, 0.55000000000000004}"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "curvePoint",
                    "cornerRadius": 0,
                    "curveFrom": "{0.29234067433248878, 1}",
                    "curveMode": 1,
                    "curveTo": "{0.29234067433248878, 1}",
                    "hasCurveFrom": false,
                    "hasCurveTo": false,
                    "point": "{0.29234067433248878, 1}"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

its svg code is

```
<g id="Facebook">
    <circle id="Oval" fill="#5B76AF" cx="25" cy="25" r="25"></circle>
    <path d="M26.5497954,40 L26.5497954,26.5 L30.3751705,26.5 L31,20.5 L26.5497954,20.5 L26.5497954,17.578 C26.5497954,16.033 26.5866303,14.5 28.6016371,14.5 L30.6425648,14.5 L30.6425648,10.21 C30.6425648,10.1455 28.8894952,10 27.1159618,10 C23.4120055,10 21.0927694,12.4855 21.0927694,17.05 L21.0927694,20.5 L17,20.5 L17,26.5 L21.0927694,26.5 L21.0927694,40 L26.5497954,40 Z" id="facebook-[#176]" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
</g>
```

I understand `<circle />` comes from the first layer, which i have no trouble with it, the issue is second layer, `path` which is f letter, as its sketch json points are mapped to `<path d="M26.5497954,40 L26.5497954,26.5 L30.3751705,26.5 L31,20.5 L26.5497954,20.5 L26.5497954,17.578 C26.5497954,16.033 26.5866303,14.5 28.6016371,14.5 L30.6425648,14.5 L30.6425648,10.21 C30.6425648,10.1455 28.8894952,10 27.1159618,10 C23.4120055,10 21.0927694,12.4855 21.0927694,17.05 L21.0927694,20.5 L17,20.5 L17,26.5 L21.0927694,26.5 L21.0927694,40 L26.5497954,40 Z" id="facebook-[#176]" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>`

which is something i am trying hard to crack.. Is there a pattern to turn sketch json points to svg path and how can i do it..

Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand SVG paths like `M26.54,40 L26.54,26.5 C30.64,10.14 Z`? If not, I would start with reading [SVG Paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths).

Comment: @Codo i do understand both M, L, C, Z, issue is converting json points to these numbers after M, i.e M26.53,40 L26.54 etc..

Comment: Hi, JohnPep! Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the full solution but a few good hints:

**Coordinates**

All layers seem to use a local coordinate system with *x* and *y* values between 0 and 1. So you need the layers size and position to calculate the coordinates used in SVG:

x<sub>svg</sub> = frame.x + x<sub>layer</sub> * frame.width

y<sub>svg</sub> = frame.y + y<sub>layer</sub> * frame.height

**Commands**

The mapping of commands is trickier as the Sketch system uses a model different from SVG. The main difference is: SVG uses commands to represent path segments (except for the starting *M*) while Sketch uses a list of points that are either sharp or soft *corners*. In order to derive the command, you need to look at two consecutive points. Let's call them *p1* and *p2*:

*p1.hasCurveFrom = false* and *p2.hasCurveTo = false*:

That represents a straight line, thus the *L* command. The coordinate is taken from *p2.point*.

*p1.hasCurveFrom = true* and *p2.hasCurveTo = true*:

That represents a cubic spline, thus the *C* command. The three coordinates are taken from:

1. *p1.curveFrom*
2. *p2.curveTo*
3. *p2.point*

**Further hints**

The path starts with an *M* command to *p.point* of the first point.

The attribute `"isClosed": true` obviously indicates a closed path. Therefore, the commands end with `Z` to close the path.

There are probably many more subtleties that I don't know.

If you want to implement a full Sketch to SVG converter, you will also need to implement the different shape classes and not just *triangle*, *oval* and *shapePath* and you will need to take care of all the other attributes like *isFlippedHorizontal*, *isFlippedVertical*, *rotation*, *cornerRadius*, *resizingType* etc.